Native javascript events triggered by wire:model update
I'm trying to run a client javascript function when a form element gets updated by wire:model changes on the client side. I know Livewire doesn't trigger a change event, but I've read that input and livewire:update are both emitted. I don't see it working, though.
<input type="hidden" wire:model.live="thing1" id="thingid" />

<script>
    // I'm trying 'input' and 'livewire:update'
    document.getElementById('thingid').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        console.log('this never gets called');
    });
</script>


Am I just barking up the wrong tree?

input element events? lost of dev's will use keyup. apply it to all input's and use e.target to differentiate.

Sorry. I had <input type="input", but it's actually type="hidden"

Events are not raised if you fill the input via code
